# How to return a message when a try to login to the website failed, because the user does not exist/password/username arent correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I built a website as my project for school. I built a registration system, but I have a problem: I want the user to recive a message from the server when the login proccess fails, and everything goes right, except from the message. Somehow, though everything is right, the user doesnt get any message from the server at all. He is only redirected, as the code is programmed. I followed the course of events and it seems that it should show a message, but in reality its not.

Im using aspx.

MasterPage.aspx:

```
<section>
<table id='tblog' border='0'>
    <%=hello %>
    <%=logIn %>
    <%=topPanel %>
    <%=msgError %>
    </table>
</section>
```

MasterPage.aspx.cs

```
public string msgError = "";
if  (Request.Form["submit1"] != null)
{

    nameen = Request.Form["nameen"];
    password  = Request.Form["password"];

    query = "select * from Users";
    query += " WHERE Name  = '" + nameen + "'";
    query += " AND PWD  = '" + password + "'";


    SqlDataReader data = DalBll.DataReadSQL(DalBll.GetConnection(), query);
    if (data.Read())
    {
        ///(I DELETED THIS PART)
    }
    else
    {
        msgError += "<tr><td colspan='2'><div>WRONG PASSWORD/USERNAME</div></td></tr>";
    }
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**!

Comment: Security is _hard_.  Do not reinvent the wheel.  You should use an existing, proven, authentication system.

Comment: @SLaks is right, there is a lot wrong with this code.  The answer to your question however appears to be that you populate the `msgError` variable nicely enough, but then just redirect.  The user probably doesnt even have time to see it even if you did show it.

Comment: Why do you think assigning "msgError" a value would display something to the user?  In addition, redirecting the page would wipe out any messages displayed on the screen.

Comment: @RickS: He has ` <%=msgError %>` in his ASPX.

Comment: @SLaks  Yea, i see that now.  It's the redirecting that's the problem.

Comment: Hey guys. About the security issues - I agree with you, but this is how my school wants it to be like. Thanks about the answer @paqogomez
I solved my case. Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

There are many documented ways to display information to the user.  One way to do this is to use a javascript alert.

Replace `Response.Redirect()` with this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + msgError + "');", true);
```